# Change column data type and format

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

When importing the excel to access 2007, some date field had become text field. so i want to run query in access to change those columns data type to datetime. How can i pass  the date format ("dd-mmm-yyyy") in sql ?

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl1 
ALTER COLUMN [ABC] datetime
```

Thanks

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have imported a column (field) from Excel and it has ended up in text format, you should be very wary of simply switching to a date time format. Access should already have interpreted the field as DateTime if it did not see it as mixed data type. You should create a new DateTime column and update it with the year month and day in an unambiguous format.

Let us say your column is mm/dd/yyyy, one option would be:

```
UPDATE Table SET NewDateTime = Right(DT,4) & "/" & Left(DT,2) & "/" & Mid(DT,4,2)
WHERE DT Like "##/##/####"
```

You cannot set the Format property with DDL and it is of no relevance outside MS Access. In general, I recommend that you do not use the Format property in tables, it is best controlled in forms and reports. Setting a format will inevitably confuse someone at some stage when a query does not work in the expected way.

If you really must set a format, you must use VBA, DAO and the TableDef.

```
Dim db As Database
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim prp As Property
Dim prpName As String
Dim prpValue As String
Dim prpType As Long

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set tdf = db.TableDefs("Table1")
    Set fld = tdf.Fields("ADate")

    prpName = "Format"
    prpValue = "yyyy/mm/dd"
    prpType = dbText

    On Error Resume Next
    fld.Properties(prpName) = prpValue

    If Err.Number = 3270 Then
        Set prp = fld.CreateProperty(prpName, prpType, prpValue)
        Err.Clear
        fld.Properties.Append prp
    End If

    Debug.Print fld.Properties("Format")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cDate

```
cDate(rst.fields("fieldname"))
```

That should fix your issue.