# How to remove long text format "@" (MS Access)

Tags: ms-access, longtext

I'm working with access office 365 MSO.
While importing excel files into access, sometimes long text columns will be assigned with the format "@". This somehow can lead to truncate the content. Currently I manually have to remove this "@" symbol, however the goal would be, to have a VBA code which would remove all "@" for long text columns, for all existing tables inside the DB.

I found this post [Change column data type and format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555569/change-column-data-type-and-format), however my knowledge of VBA is not sufficient to solve the issue. Could someone help?

[Example of a long text column with format "@"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsbOW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place code in a procedure in general module and run it there or call from another procedure.

```
Sub DelFmt()
Dim def As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim prpName As String
prpName = "Format"
For Each def In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If Not def.name Like "?Sys*" And Not def.name Like "f*" Then
        For Each fld In def.Fields
            On Error Resume Next
            fld.Properties(prpName) = "@"
            If Err.Number <> 3270 Then
                fld.Properties.Delete prpName
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @June7, thanks a lot for this fast and solving answer. It did work :)